# c++ Remove substring after last match of substring

Tags: c++, string

What is a compact way of removing the last part of a string after the last occurrence of a given substring, including it?
In terms of bash parameter substitution it would be the equivalent of:

```
VAR=${VAR%substring*}
```

Is there a library (e.g. boost) supporting replacement with wildcards or something similar?

Comment: "Is there a library (e.g. boost) supporting replacement with wildcards or something similar?" Regular expressions?

Answer (score 2):

Without wildcards, the solution I've found is as follows

```
string.erase(string.rfind("substring"));
```

Provided substring is found in string

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
  std::string st = "abcedfgsubstring1234";
  auto pos = st.rfind("substring");
  if (pos != std::string::npos) {
    st.resize(pos);
  }
  std::cout << st << std::endl;
}
```

If `substring` is not found, do nothing.